# Payara vs Glassfish performance

Tags: performance, payara

I've an JSF application witch runs very smooth & fast on Glassfish 4.1 . After migrating to Payara 4 we observe considerable slowdown. Each response is about 4-5x slower. We got same Mojarra version, same jdbc pool settings, thread pools and EJB container too. Only Weld is never on Payara. Project_stage is set to 'Production'.

Any sugestions ??

Comment: I would suggest looking over differences in the Java memory settings (when payara is started). There are a few things you can/should set in GlassFish/Payara in order to tune the performance. There is for example an article about this on the Payara blog, https://blog.payara.fish/fine-tuning-payara-server-5-in-production. This is just the tip of the iceberg though.

Comment: in my opinion JVM settings are not an issue. All jmv params seems to be the same. One difference is downgraded Eclipselink (from 2.6 to 2.5.2) because we got an issue with ManyToOne relationships.

Comment: These are not merely JVM params. These are tuning parameters  - there are some notable changes between the two and also differences in how you set them up for production.